# Using Oracle DB from C#-VS2005

Tags: oracle

Oracle installed on the server is 10.2.0.3  Enterprise Edition 64bit (10g).

ODAC is showing version as 10.2.0.2.20 is on a Windows 2008 x64 machine.

Error I run into when I run my app in my test environment in above machine is

```
The type initializer for 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection' threw an exception.
```

I tried using .Net Oracle namespace and I get this using a version from 
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727

Error:

```
Oracle client libraries threw BadImageFormatException.  This problem will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed.
```

Anyone run into such an issue?

Also what is the right Oracle Client/ODAC to use on Windows 2008 x64 machine? Anyonen have a link?

Comment: I think there is a 64 bit version of OracleClient available as part of one of the service packs for .net 3.5 http://support.microsoft.com/kb/959209 That may, however, be of no use to you though if you are still using .net 2.0 (vs 2005). Refer http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfx64bit/thread/3cbc1c81-e0a8-4d00-b0a6-55be2c099bf5 as well for more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have installed the 32 bits Oracle client, or you must have a 32 dll masking your 64bits client.  You need to install the 64bits client so that 64 bits dll can be accessed by your app.  Look for an oci*.dll in your path.

Also look into the registry under `hklm\software\oracle` to see how many 'homes' you have.

Finally if you have toad on that client look at the home selector in the connection dialog box. It will show incomplete or inoperative homes in red.

Comment: But if i access the x64 from my C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727, I should get the x64 of System.Data.oracleCclient.dll, correct?

Comment: _home1, _home2, _home4 is what i see in the registry

Comment: each of these homes correspond to a previous install and there must be a folder associated under that key.  May be one of these is a former 32bits install that is still in your PATH. To make sure what DLL gets loaded, use the sysinternals suite (eg.process explorer or filemon).

Comment: This is the PATH values:E:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\bin;E:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_2\bin;E:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_4\bin;E:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_3\bin;

Comment: Then you need to check whether the oci dlls in `E:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\bin` are 32 or 64 bits.  Use the VisualStudio dumpbin tool for this dumpbin /header oci.dll etc...

Comment: Thankks Alain, dumpbin tool indicates 32Bit version

Comment: Then you need to find which of your install is 64 bits and update your path accordingly (remove all other client_x entries).  A more radical approach would be to remove all these PATH entries and corresponding homes en reinstall 64bits ODAC or at least 64bits ODP.net.

Comment: All homes are 32B...guess the support team did not install the right 64b version. Is there a different folder i should check to see if they did innstall 64b odp.net?

Comment: Nope. Sorry, you need to install the ODAC at [http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html][http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html] (you might need to register).  The 64bits 10.2.0.3 version is compatible with .net 2.0